# Linear Programming: List of all solutions generated using DocPlex in PYTHON (failing with the cplex solution pool)?

Tags: python-3.x, linear-programming, cplex, mixed-integer-programming, docplex

I am actually facing an issue in the resolution of a problem. My problem is a Liner Programing problem with optimization of the food diet and minimization of the cost. As the problem is similar to this one (https://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/mp/diet.html), I have installed docplex in Python to solve it and it works!
The problem is I need to access to all the feasible solutions and export them. But the IBM example only gives me access to the best solution.
Therefore, I have added the solution pool function to get access to all the solutions:

```
def soln_pool(mdl):
    cpx = mdl.get_cplex()
    cpx.populate_solution_pool()
    numsol = cpx.solution.pool.get_num()
    print("The solution pool contains %d solutions." % numsol)

    sol_pool = []

    for i in range(numsol):
        x_i = cpx.solution.pool.get_values(i)
        nb_vars = len(x_i)
        sol = []
        for k in range(nb_vars):
            sol.append(x_i[k])
        sol_pool.append(sol)
    results=sol_pool
    return(results)

results=soln_pool(mdl)

for k,solution in enumerate(results):
    label=data.index
matrix_results=pd.DataFrame()

for k,solution in enumerate(results):
    matrix_results[str(k)]=solution
matrix_results.index=data.index
```

The only problem is this approaches gives me approximately 30 solutions when thousends should be available. I assume it is because the population of the solution pool is limited around 30 solutions. Therefore I have changed the parameters to populate my solution pool with more solutions as described on the IBM website (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/12.9.0?topic=solutions-how-enumerate-all) and on some other pages ([How to increase number of Cplex solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60759169/how-to-increase-number-of-cplex-solutions)):

```
def soln_pool(mdl):
    cpx = mdl.get_cplex()
    
    cpx.parameters.mip.pool.intensity.set(4)
    cpx.parameters.mip.pool.absgap.set(0.0)
    cpx.parameters.mip.limits.populate.set(2 000 000)   
    cpx.populate_solution_pool()
    numsol = cpx.solution.pool.get_num()
    print("The solution pool contains %d solutions." % numsol)

    sol_pool = []

    for i in range(numsol):
        x_i = cpx.solution.pool.get_values(i)
        nb_vars = len(x_i)
        sol = []
        for k in range(nb_vars):
            sol.append(x_i[k])
        sol_pool.append(sol)
    results=sol_pool
    return(results)

results=soln_pool(mdl)

for k,solution in enumerate(results):
    label=data.index
matrix_results=pd.DataFrame()

for k,solution in enumerate(results):
    matrix_results[str(k)]=solution
matrix_results.index=data.index


with pd.ExcelWriter('Results.xlsx') as writer:
    data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data')
    matrix_results.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Solutions')
```

But with this I have even less solution! (only one).
I assume my mistake comes from the part:

```
for k in range(nb_vars):
    sol.append(x_i[k])
sol_pool.append(sol)
```

but unfortunately I can not find where.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: In my experience, sometimes you need to set a small gap (instead of zero).

Comment: Here is an example where I needed to use a nonzero gap for Cplex to enumerate all solutions: https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2018/11/chess-and-solution-pool.html.

Answer (score 0):

The "populate solution pool" functionality is not meant to generate *all* possible solutions, but only to generate *some* alternative (non-optimal) solutions.
See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/20.1.0?topic=pool-what-is-populating-solution
for more details.
Unfortunately, there is no way in Cplex to enumerate all feasible solutions of a MIP problems. CPLEX is built to find an *optimal* solution. Instead, you should consider using Constraint-based programming (docplex.cp) for that purpose.

In addition, you mention installing Docplex, but your example is based on the Cplex matrix-based API. Since version 2.16, Docplex supports the populate functionality, search for `populate` in the Docplex documentation here:

http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/mp/docplex.mp.model.html

Comment: The solution pool can actually generate *all* solutions (for problems that have not really an infinite number of different solutions).

Comment: What I meant was, CPLEX's solution pool stores solutions, unlike CPO's way of searching for the "next" solution. In practice, setting a high capacity of the pool is likely to blow up in memory.

Comment: Also generating all feasible solutions is no problem (either use a large enough gap or use a dummy objective). Again assuming no capacity problems.

Comment: OK, my bad, you're right, your chess example is very nice, though rather non-standard.

Comment: I tried your queens sample in Docplex and found it even more dicey than you observed: the size of the pool depends not only on the absgap and integraility tolerance, but also on #threads and random seed (controlling heuristics)

Comment: I don't really know what to conclude from that, except to say that obviously a different tree will be developed.